# MockMVC content is missing

Tags: java, junit, mockito, mockmvc

The content from MockMvc managed to have status code but missing the data.

Test class:

```
@Test
public void shouldReturnAll() throws Exception {
    when(userService.getAll()).thenReturn(users); // note that 'users' is not empty, I already checked.

    MvcResult response = this.mvc.perform(get("/users"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.data", hasSize(2)))
            .andReturn();
 
}
```

Reponse:

```
MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 200
    Error message = null
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json"]
     Content type = application/json
             Body = {"status":"success"}
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
```

I think it has something to do with Response object in my Controller class.

Controller:

```
@GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Response> getAll() {
        List<User> users = userService.getAll();
        Response resp = new Response(StatusMessage.SUCCESS, users);
        return new ResponseEntity<Response>(resp, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

*****Edit*****: Another test which works (getting a single User):

```
@Test
public void getUserByIdTest() throws Exception {
            when(this.userService.getUserById(any(Long.class))).thenReturn(user);

    MvcResult response = this.mvc.perform(get("/users/{id}", user.getId()))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.data.id", is(user.getId().intValue())))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.data.name", is(user.getName())))
            .andReturn();
}
```

Controller:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Response> getUserById(@PathVariable Long id) throws Exception {
    try {
        User user = userService.getUserById(id);
        Response resp = new Response(StatusMessage.SUCCESS, user);
        return new ResponseEntity<Response>(resp, HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Response object class:

```
@Data
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class Response<T> {

    private String status;
    private T data;

    public Response(StatusMessage status, T data) {
        this.status = status.getStatusMessage();
        this.data = data;
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the `Response` class code or include the import if it's a part of an external library?

Comment: @Jonasz I have another test for getting a single User and the data returns just fine.
The only difference between these two tests is the one here uses a List<User> and the other one use only User. I have no clue why.

Comment: Could you show the other test and the controller method it's testing as well as the `Response` class?

Comment: I added the test that works below

Comment: And are you 100% sure that `users` object returned from the mocked service is not empty? This and the `JsonInclude` `NON_EMPTY` would explain the missing field in response. Could you show the creation of the `users` object in the test?